# How to export print output to Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, export

Whenever there is a matching keyword, my code prints the next line. I'm trying to export the entire print output to an excel file automatically. The code works perfectly for printing the output
in the IDE terminal, but I can't seem to export it to excel. The for loop is giving me trouble. Which ever command I try, ends up giving an error. Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.

**Sample text to try the code on:**

```
Hi, please enter name

Ricky

can you please enter last name

Martin

Please enter the full name

Ricky Martin
```

**Output:**

```
Ricky

Martin

Ricky Martin
```

**Question**

How to get these outputs exported to a column in Excel?

```
import xlsxwriter

excelFile = xlsxwriter.Workbook ("goal.xlsx")
workSheet = excelFile.add_worksheet ()

with open("filepath.txt", 'r') as f:

   for line in f:
        if "enter" in line:
            result = print(next (f, ''))
            workSheet.write('A1', result)
            

excelFile.close()
```

Comment: You have not shown how you want your output data to look like in Excel.

Comment: You don't have any code in your example writing to the workSheet object.  Take a look here - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

Comment: @JustinEzequiel thank you for commenting. The output data should go to any column in excel. 

For example it can go in column A and look like this:
Ricky

Martin

Ricky Martin.
 
I hope I'm making sense. I tried to add this line of code in my question above, but it's not working.

Comment: @RiskyMick thank you for commenting. Just added that part of code in the original question. but it doesn't work. I have gone through the documentation link but can't figure out the issue.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve what you want to do is to just write to a csv file. Import this csv file in excel and you are done. CSV is a widely supported filetype for python and super easy to implement. It does not change anything with respect to immediately formatting it to an excel file as you have to 'open' the excel file as well as 'import' the csv file in excel.

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn Using the .csv idea worked for me. Didn't know it could be done like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can see you have a print statement for result. So it returns None. Could be the issue.

I haven't worked with xlsxwriter much. But, I have a working pandas example which is fairly simple and works with list so that you can get a pointer.

```
import pandas as pd
lstSrc=[1,2,3,4]
df=pd.DataFrame() 
df["TimeTook"] = lstSrc
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("result.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='sheetname')
writer.save()
```

Referred [xlsxwriter docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) for sample.